# Delphi Stringlist in Record

Tags: delphi, record, tstringlist

Is it possible to have a stringlist in a record? EG

```
TImportStats = record
  ATotal:Integer;
  BTotal:String;
  AList:TStringist;
end;
```

and if I presume I would need to create it before using the record?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whilst this is perfectly legal, it may be prudent to find another way.  You pinpoint the issue when you said:

> I presume I would need to create it
>   before using the record

Not only that, but you need to find a good time to destroy it too. If you forget to do so there will be no errors but your program will leak memory.

If the record is the *owner* of the string list then you may be better off containing it inside a class. That way the construction and destruction of the string list will follow the constructor/destructor pattern that all Delphi developers are familiar with.

If the record does not own the string list, but just takes a reference to it during the lifetime of the string list, then a record is fine.  But if you do it this way make sure that the record's lifetime is contained within the string list's lifetime so that you don't carry around a stale reference.

Comment: Also, it is important for the OP to understand that an object record member is just a pointer to the object. That is, if `a` and `b` are two records of type `TImportStats`, then `a := b` will make `a` and `b` point to *the same* `TStringList` object, so any chagnes to `a.AList` will also affect `b.AList` and vice versa. In addition, the old `AList` of `a` will be left in memory but there will be no way of accessing it, so there is a memory leak (unless you have stored a pointer to the object somewhere else in your program). Of course David knows this; I'm just expaining to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this should work.  AList will (not be useable) until you create the stringlist.  So you can use other elements of the record without creating the stringlist, but you must create the stringlist element prior to using it.  Also, you are responsible for freeing each stringlist when you're done.

Comment: It is a pointer not a managed type, I think it would point to an arbitrary location until it is assigned something.

Comment: Note that if you use the record in an assignment like R2 := R1, only the pointer is assigned.  Both records will point to the *same* StringList.

Comment: @Chris, @Sertac: That depends on where `ImportStats: TImportStats` is declared. If it is a local variable, @Sertac is right -- it will be "assigned" but pointing to garbage (and, of course, there will be no `TStringList` object). On the other hand, if it is a global variable, declared somewhere in the `implementation` section, it will be filled with zeroes, that is, `nil`.

Comment: And, of course, @Robert's comment is extremely important to understand.

Comment: @Sertac, An instance of the record will point somewhere, but I expect that the AList field will be nil until it's been assigned to something.

Comment: @Robert - and the cool bug that's easy to introduce here is that if you assign this way, but think that you really have two stringlists, you A) end up with all sorts of confusion, including duplicating changes (changes to one affect the "other"), and B) freeing and nilling one will free the other, but won't nil it.

Comment: @Chris - Andreas is right, if it is global or in a class it will be nil, if local, no.

Comment: @Chris, you are wrong. Try `procedure MyProc; var ImportStats: TImportStats; begin ShowMessage(BoolToStr(Assigned(ImportStats.AList), true)); end;`. Notice that `Assigned(ImportStats.AList)` is exactly equivalent to `ImportStats.AList <> nil`.

Comment: @All - point taken on nil vs 0. But it still won't be usable until you create and assign a stringlist, unless Robert's scenario is what you want.

Comment: @Andreas - add this line to your test, and you'll see that the stringlist is not ready for use:
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(ImportStats.AList.Count));

Comment: @Chris: Of course it isn't ready for use! There is no `TStringList` object! All I am saying is that it is "assigned", where "assigned" means that the pointer is non-zero. Before a `TStringList` is created and assigned to the member `AList`, this pointer will point to garbage, as I said. That is, your statement "AList will be nil" is incorrect (for example if the record is a local variable). `AList` is non-nil, but points to garbage.

Comment: I have edited my answer to remove the erroneous info about nil.

Comment: @Chris, now I can give you a +1! :)

Comment: @Chris, you can't use other parts of the record just as you can't use the StringList itself. If the record is instantiated on stack the content will be random. In this respect a record, works more like a collection of separate variables: You can't use a TStringList declared as a local variable before you initialize it, just as you can't use an `var i:Integer` before you initialize it. No difference.

Comment: @Cosmin: I think Chris just says that you can do `ATotal := 5` right away, but you cannot do `AList.Add('alpha')` unless you first create the object by `AList := TStringList.Create`.

Comment: @Cosmin, sure. But you can start assigning the simple members right away. My point was (and I believe that was the OP question), that you have to create the stringlist before using it.

Comment: @Chris, I think the explanation is simply ambiguous, because "assignment" is not the only possible use for the other elements. When you say `you can use other elements of the record without ...` what's stopping me for interpreting it as `you can do SomethingElse := Record.SomeValue`? And if Assignment is the most important operation to be done on "elements", you can also assign the StringList!

Answer (score 0):

If the stringlist is only going to be used in the local scope of the TImportStats record,
you might want to look at a [StringList value implementation](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/25670) in Code  Central.

This avoids the try, create, finally, destroy overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's probably late, but the most elegant way to solve your problem, would be to create a subclass of TStringList with ATotal and BTotal as the two new elements in it. Then you can simply create and destroy it as you see fit. This solution is clean and simple.